# How can I play as a band?

Tags: starbound

I'm trying to play as a band in Starbound, but it seems that the songs won't sync with my other band mates. How can I succesfully play a song as a band?

Comment: Perhaps timing, and a little bit of luck?  Your bandmates may have to compensate for lag, but if they start playing when you hit a beat, it might help the music sync up.

Comment: You're all entering the same band name?

Comment: Yes we do, we even entered simple names like "A".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be fairly straight forward, and I haven't had any trouble with it (at least not with the bundled starter songs). I have only been playing on a very low latency server, however.

- Select the same song to play
- Enter the same band name
- Press play roughly at the same time

Note that for some songs not all instruments will start playing right away, since you'll be playing different parts of the song depending on your instrument.

Answer (score 0):

It's really Easy.

You all should have the same .abc music file and enter your band name (My friends and i use "Human") and then hit play at the same time :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply, choose different parts of the same song, enter band name (Eaglestar FTW!) and press play at the same time.